# With PowerShell, how can I get Write-Debug output to appear in the console?

Tags: powershell

I'm learning PowerShell and was using [Write-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Host) to check variable assignments in a new PowerShell script file. Then I read an article suggesting this was a bad idea.

So, in my .ps1 file I replaced statements like this:

```
Write-Host "Start"
Write-Host "End"
```

... with this:

```
Write-Debug "Start"
Write-Debug "End"
```

But when I ran the saved script in Windows PowerShell ISE no output was written to the console. I appended `-debug` to the statement that calls the script, like so:

```
PS E:\trialrun> .\MyScript.ps1 -debug
```

But again, the output doesn't get written to the console. Apparently I'm using Write-Debug incorrectly.  How can I get the debug output to write to the console?

Comment: change `Write-Debug "Start"` to `Write-Debug "Start" -debug` in the script (instead of trying to bind it when you call the script) then do the same with the End one. Or else check [out this answer on binding parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159066/print-debug-messages-to-console-from-a-powershell-function-that-returns/10159250#10159250) such as debug.

Comment: The link seems to be broken.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

- Run `$DebugPreference = 'Continue'` to start seeing output from `Write-Debug` calls.
- When you're done, restore preference variable `$DebugPreference` to its default value, using `$DebugPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'`
- To turn on debug output for a given cmdlet or advanced function only, use the `-Debug` common parameter.

  - *Caveat*: In *Windows PowerShell* (but no longer in PowerShell [Core] v6+, this will present an interactive debugging prompt for every `Write-Debug` statement encountered.

---

Whether output from `Write-Debug` statements is printed is controlled by two mechanisms:

- **Scope-wide**: by the value of the **`$DebugPreference` preference variable** - see [`Get-Help about_Preference_Variables`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables).
- **Ad-hoc, command-scoped**, when calling a cmdlet or *advanced* script/function (which overrides the `$DebugPreference` value) with the **`-Debug` common parameter** - see [`Get-Help about_CommonParameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters).

`$DebugPreference` defaults to `SilentlyContinue`, which explains why you don't see any output from `Write-Debug` statements by default.

When you use **common parameter `-Debug`**, you effectively set `$DebugPreference` *for the invoked command only*, and:

- in **Windows PowerShell**, you ***invariably* set it to the value `Inquire`**, which **not only *prints* `Write-Debug` messages, but also *pauses* at every such statement to ask how you want to proceed**.
- in **PowerShell [Core] v6+**, the value is now (more sensibly) set to **`Continue`**.

  - For a custom script or function to support the `-Debug` common parameter, it must be an [*advanced*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced) one, declared with the `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute for its `param()` block, as [Mathias' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45289842/45375) shows.

**Since, in *Windows PowerShell*, this prompt-at-every-`Write-Debug`-call behavior can be *disruptive*, `$DebugPreference = 'Continue'` may be the better approach.**
As stated, in PowerShell [Core] v6+ this is no longer a concern.

Note: If, from inside an advanced function or script, you want to distinguish between `$DebugPreference` having been set as a *preference variable* by the caller vs. *common parameter* `-Debug` having been passed (which is translated to a function/script-local `$DebugPreference` variable), use
`$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Debug')`; `$true` indicates that `-Debug` was used.

---

Reference official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-debug

> By default, debug messages are not displayed in the console, but you
> can display them by using the Debug parameter or the $DebugPreference
> variable.

Comment: Thanks. That's a cool way to do it. I didn't know the arguments could be queried for keys like that. Instead, I actually had ended up writing an if ($DebugPreference -eq 'Inquire' ) statement to check, and then if true setting $DebugPreference = 'Continue'  It would be easier if clients always had PS6.

Answer (score 20):

You'll need a `CmdletBinding` attribute in your script if you want support for common parameters (including `-Debug`):

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param()

Write-Debug Start
Write-Debug End
```

I'd suggest having a look at the [`about_Functions_CmdletBindingAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute) help file

Comment: That's good advice in general, but, unlike other common parameters such as `-ErrorAction`, `-Debug` doesn't allow you to pass a _specific value_ for the implied, command-scoped `$DebugPreference` variable and instead invariably sets it to `Inquire`, which means that every `Write-Debug` statement encountered will _prompt_, which is disruptive, if your only intent is to _print_ debug messages.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me - `testscript.ps1`:

```
param(
    [switch]$Debug = $false
)

if ( $Debug ) {
    $DebugPreference = "Continue"
}

Write-Debug "This is a test"
```

This way I can run my script with:

```
./testscript -Debug
```

or without the `-Debug` if I don't want the output.

Comment: Good answer. You may want to look into doing an if check on `$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Debug')` because if you eventually convert to an advanced function, the Debug switch here will conflict with the one that `Cmdletbinding()` adds.

Answer (score 0):

If you place `$DebugPreference = 'Continue'` in the process block of each module function, it will work as intended. A bit of duplication, but that's far easier than some of the other solutions suggested.