# Standard output in powershell debug console

Tags: powershell

I have a long script in powershell which calls an even longer function located in a separate .ps1 file. The function runs some `svn update` commands and some compiled executables which produce standard output. When I run these directly from the script the output gets redirected to the debug console in `Powershell ISE`. When I run them through the function I can tell they are running but I get no standard output in the console.

How do I redirect standard output from my function back to the powershell debug console where I can see it?

THanks.

**EDIT**

I am importing the function as follows:

```
. "D:\common.ps1"
```

and calling it as follows:

```
$MedianValue = Run-Comparison $LastRev $FirstRev $ScriptPath $SolutionPath $DevenvPath $TestPath $refFile $SVNPAth
```

Within the function, one of the calls is as follows

`svn update $FirstRev`
`Start-Process ExecutableName Argument`

It is for the above two statements that I cannot see the standard output for when I call their containing function.

Comment: Yeah that talks about redirecting to text files. I need to redirect to console...

Comment: Well after thinking aboout it, the interaction with the ISE and redirecting normal/success out won't work. Your best option might be integrating write-debug commands in the common.ps1 --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/45289842/6811411

Comment: Could you take a look at the two commands I added in my edit? Those are the ones I need to see the output for... Can I use `Write-Debug` on those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're capturing a script's / function's output and that script / function contains a mix of PowerShell-native output statements and external-program calls producing stdout output, *both* types of output are sent to PowerShell's regular success output streams.

Therefore, **unless you *redirect at the source*, you cannot *selectively* pass stdout from external programs through to the the host (e.g., a regular console window or the console pane in the ISE)**, because you won't be able to tell which output objects (lines) come from where.

To redirect at the source - if you have control over the callee's source code - you have several options, the simplest being `Write-Host`, as the following example demonstrates:

```
function Run-Comparison {
  'PS success output'
  cmd /c 'echo external stdout output' | Write-Host
}

# Captures 'PS success output', but passes the cmd.exe output through to the console.
$MedianValue = Run-Comparison
```

The above selectively sends the `cmd.exe` command's output to the host.

In PSv5+, where `Write-Host` writes to the newly introduced *information stream* (number `6`), you can optionally suppress the to-host output with `6>$null` on invocation.

To reverse the logic, use `Write-Information` instead of `Write-Host` (PSv5+ only), which is silent by default and allows you to turn on output with `$InformationPreference = 'Continue'`.

If you want silent-by-default behavior in PSv4-, use `Write-Verbose` or `Write-Debug`, but note that such output will be a different color, with each line having a prefix (`VERBOSE:` and `DEBUG:`, respectively).

Comment: Your answer is very close to being satisfactory. `Write-Host` works for `svn` and `devenv` type commands inside my function. I am now getting some of the desired output. For one last command, however, I tried `Start-Process -FilePath "Exec.exe" -ArgumentList "test" -Wait | Write-Host`, and it still opens up a new cmd window. I also tried `-NoNewWindow` but then the command fails claiming it cannot find the file.

Comment: @user32882: Try `-NoNewWindow` in combination with `-FilePath ($PWD.ProviderPath + '\Exec.exe')` (and no piping to `Write-Host`). However, if `Exec.exe` is a console application, why don't you just invoke it directly, just like `svn` and `devenv`? `.\Exec.exe test | Write-Host`

Comment: @user32882: Glad to hear it; my pleasure.