# How to delete data from oracle table using powershell

Tags: .net, oracle, powershell, odac

I want to delete the whole data from oracle table before inserting the data using powershell,

```
Add-Type -Path C:\Users\sankar\ODP.NET_Managed_ODAC122cR1\odp.net\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
#Database Connection String & Establish connection
$compConStr = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxxxx)(PORT=xxxxx)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID =xxxxxxxx)));User Id=spcl_init;Password=xxxxxx;Pooling=False"
$connection = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($compConStr)
$connection.open()
$Grouplists = Import-Csv "\\XXX\Techsupportgroups1.csv"
#Deleate existing data from oracle table
 $query = "DELETE FROM TableName"

            $command=$connection.CreateCommand()
            $command.CommandText=$query
            #$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            $command.ExecuteReader()
#Insert memebers details into oracle Table
foreach ($Group in $Grouplists){
$MembersList=(Get-QADGroupMember $Group.Group_DL |Get-QADuser -Properties * |where {$_.Type -ne "group" -and $_.AccountIsDisabled -ne "False" -and $_.Samaccountname -notmatch "unixlinuxops"} | Select-Object |Select-Object @{n='Group_Name';e={$Group.Group_Name}},Samaccountname,NTAccountName,UserPrincipalName)

        foreach($Member in $MembersList)
        {
            $GroupName = $Member.Group_Name
            $SamAccountName=$Member.SamAccountName
            $NTAccountName = $Member.NTAccountName
            $UserPrincipleName =$Member.userprincipalname

            $query = "INSERT INTO IVISTA_RBAC (Group_Name, SamAccountName,NTAccountName,UserPrincipalName)  
                                        VALUES ('$GroupName','$SamAccountName','$NTAccountName', '$UserPrincipleName')"

            $command=$connection.CreateCommand()
            $command.CommandText=$query
            $ds = New-Object system.Data.DataSet
            $da = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter($command)
            [void]$da.fill($ds)
        } 
}
$connection.Close()
```

The above code will insert the data into table, but its not deleting the data from table before inserting,

Comment: Depending upon your needs, `truncate table` may be a better fit. It is far more efficient than your delete as it doesn't generate redo. It is however, irreversible, performs an implied commit because it is DDL, not DML,  and foreign key relationships are not handled (an error is thrown). I have tables with several million rows, my analysts were doing deletes that took 15+ minutes. We replaced delete with truncate that takes microseconds.

Answer (score 0):

In this snippet, you have the `ExecuteNonQuery` commented out, but that's the command you need to use instead of the `ExecuteReader`.

```
 $query = "DELETE FROM TableName"
 $command=$connection.CreateCommand()
 $command.CommandText=$query
 #$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
 $command.ExecuteReader()
```

So it should be like this:

```
 $query = "DELETE FROM TableName"
 $command=$connection.CreateCommand()
 $command.CommandText=$query
 $command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: tried, but script got struck in running status, didnt receive any error message as well

Comment: @SankarM - Then the next step would be to debug the script and figure out where it's hanging.  You can see this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159066/print-debug-messages-to-console-from-a-powershell-function-that-returns) for some guidelines on how to do that.